# Spark running very slow on a very small data set

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce

The following simple spark program takes 4 minutes to run. I don't know what's wrong with this code.

First, I generate a VERY small rdd

```
D = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(0,[1,2,3]),(1,[2,3]),(2,[0,3]),(3,[1])]).cache()
```

Then I generate a vector

```
P1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(list(zip(list(range(4)),[1/4]*4))).cache()
```

Then I defines a function to do the `map` step

```
def MyFun(x):
    L0 = len(x[2])
    L = []
    for i in x[2]:
         L.append((i,x[1]/L0))
    return L
```

Then I execute the following code

```
P0 = P1
D0 = D.join(P1).map(lambda x: [x[0],x[1][1],x[1][0]]).cache()
C0 = D0.flatMap(lambda x: MyFun(x)).cache()
P1 = C0.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y).mapValues(lambda x:x*1.2+3.4).sortByKey().cache()
Diff = P1.join(P0).map(lambda x: abs(x[1][0]-x[1][1])).sum()
```

Given my data is so small, I couldn't figure out a reason why this piece of code runs so slow...

Comment: Why do you cache every single steps ? That costs a lot

Comment: @BlueSheepToken I thought this will help to speed up the process.... I thought if I don't cache, then it's gonna load from the disk, which gonna be slow... I guess I am wrong...Perhaps I should only cache() `D`? since I will join it later? I also tried the case to remove the 'cache()', but it still runs very slow...

Comment: The cache is writting on the disk instead of doing everything in memory, the only thing you could cache is `P1` ( I am affraid D will take longer to load from disk instead of just regenerating it). Afterwards, I strongly suggest you to use the dataframe api and not the rdd, you do not take advantage of spark doing some optimizations for you here. Have you tried profiling with Spark UI ?

Comment: @BlueSheepToken Thanks! I will try what you suggested

Comment: @fixx I will write this as an answer ! Might be clearer

Comment: @BlueSheepToken I originally tried to use Spark dataframe, then I find that it seems I cannot use `.map` to do the map step for dataframe. I have to use `sql` code to manipulate the dataframe. So I switched to rdd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197395/discussion-between-bluesheeptoken-and-ftxx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few suggestions to help you speed up this job.

#### Cache only when needed

The process of caching is to write the dag you created on the disk. So caching every step might cost a lot instead of speeding up the process.

I would suggest you to `cache` only P1.

#### Use DataFrames to allow Spark to help you

Afterwards, I strongly suggest you to use the `DataFrame` api, Spark will be able to do some optimizations for you, such as push down predicates optimizations.

The last, but not the least, using custom functions cost a lot as well. If you are using `DataFrames`, try to use only existing functions from the `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` module.

#### Profile the code with Spark UI

I also suggest to profile your code via the Spark UI, because it might not be a problem of your code since you have a small data, but a problem with the nodes.